# After sitting for a week first layer won't adhere

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion, build-plate

Last week I set up my Ender 3 V2 and it seemed to work perfectly out of the box. I leveled the bed, did a test print, and discovered that the nozzle was too low (successful print but elephant foot). Re-leveled at a slightly higher height (lower bed level) and was able to produce a very lovely benchy and dog.

Then I turned it off and let it sit a week until I had something to actually print. Now the first layer fails almost immediately. It will put down a line and when the nozzle comes back around it will knock it around producing a spaghetti monster. I've tried re-leveling, cleaning the bed with rubbing alcohol, using previous G-code that worked fine last week, positioning models in different spots on the bed when slicing, but no matter what I do, nothing seems to stick.

I've cleaned the bed as well. It is quite dusty here so it definitely needed that, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/ender-3-with-bltouch-prints-slanted-lines

Comment: Give us a picture of the result mid-print, just before the nozzle wipes it off. It can give us a ton of information.

Comment: After a week, the springs may have settled and the bed may need releveling.  Did you level the bed again?

Answer (score 2):

If your having first layer adhesion issues:

Please try one (or more) of the following (Start with #1), and remember that all of them are equally important!

1. Make sure your bed is level (Maybe use a leaving stick (or whatever those bubble things are called))
2. Be sure the bed is clean (I recommend glass cleaner 1-3 squirts and then a light scrub of a paper towel)
3. Change the temperature of your heated bed (50 - 60 °C)
4. Check your nozzle height (.15 - .25 mm is what I use)
5. Lastly, use bed adhesion. Start with painter's tape (least damaging, easy to remove), then use a glue stick or even hair spray if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.